# Can I have a one-many relationship between a super-type and each sub-type?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling, erd

I am trying to model a scenario where I have a SuperType that has 2 Sub-types.  However, each Sub-Type has several records associated with an instance of the Super-Type.

Let's say there is a Book and there are 2 types of Books and each type of book has 3 parts with different details.

Book is a SuperType. The Poem is a SubType and Short-Stories is another SubType. The book may either be an anthology of poems or short stories.

A Book of Type Poem has 3 Poems with each Poem having a different author but all 3 tied to the same Book Id.  Similarly, the book can also be a compilation of Short-Stories and each book can have many Short-Stories.

```
Book
Book1   Book1_Details
Book2   Book2_Details
Book3   Book3_Details
Book4   Book4_Details

Poem 
Book1   Poem1  Author1
Book1   Poem2  Author2
Book1   Poem3  Author3
Book2   Poem4  Author4
Book2   Poem5  Author5
Book2   Poem6  Author6
```

Similarly, Book 3 and Book 4 have 3 Short stories each.

What is the right way to model this?

```
Book
BookId BookDetails

Poem
BookId EachPoemId EachPoemDetails
```

or do I need a third entity

```
Book
BookId BookDetails

BookPoem
BookPoemId BookId PoemCollectionId

Poem
EachPoemId PoemCollectionId EachPoemDetails
```

Does each super-type have to have 1-1 between with a sub-type as in a person can either be a student or staff? How do I model the scenario that a book can be many poems or many stories?

Comment: Where are you 1st stuck in what presentation of what design method?

Comment: I am trying to come up with a logical model using Erwin data modeler. I want to know if I can have one (super-type) to many (sub-type). There are no other details that the sub-type has besides the FK (Book ID) and 4 PoemId. Should I create a Poem Collection entity  and then have one to many between PoemCollection and Poem or can Poem entity be connected to Book entity directly ?

Comment: Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens of published academic information modelling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf & html. Ask 1 specific question re what is your sticking point. Why is it you can't just follow your method? PS Basic questions are SO faqs. But clear concise phrasings of problems are needed to (re)search. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.